# Magento 1 How to redirect on current page

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1, redirect

I want to redirect to the current page and display a success message but it's redirecting to the home page.

Any solution is available?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

paste this code at the end of your controller

```
 return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/controller');
```

if You are on edit page

```
return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/controller', ['id' => "your_id"]);
```

Comment: Question is for M1